# Is there a way to close a question that you found an answer to without deleting it or answering your own question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, bad-questions

I have an answer to my question that was proposed in a comment, and deleting my question will be bad for getting the ability to ask questions back (I had one very poorly received question).

Answering my own question got downvotes too.  There are no flags that would apply here, and leaving it up is getting downvotes too.  How do I fix this?

Comment: If it's off-topic in some way higher rep users could close it. If not it might be better to accept your losses and delete it.

Comment: *"Answering my own question got downvotes too"*. This may be worth pondering over. If your answer works for your particular situation, accept it. Otherwise try to find out why the community is downvoting it, as there might be a higher chance that a better solution is available.

Comment: Others had said that chrome and firefox blocked it from happening, so that's what I put as the answer.

Comment: @CinCout the community downvited for ...[external](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366656/why-is-this-question-getting-downvotes)... reasons.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic Maybe this is one of those instances that the new blog talks about, SO being less welcoming and all?

Comment: @CinCout Ironic how one meta posts is arguing the community is plenty welcome to new users and the very next post shows the community pushing a new user away.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic Different people, different thoughts. It is as simple and as complicated as that.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with answering your own questions. But keep in mind that your answer should follow the same quality standards as any other answer. Your current attempt is a very poor quality answer. You could easily improve it. Your question is also poor quality and could be vastly improved by including a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) The answer, *"A lot. An absurd amount. More than you think you are capable of. After you have reached the end of your rope and the pain of not having the answer exceeds the vast amount of shame received by posting your question, that's when you can go ahead and ask. Because at that point, you will have done whatever research necessary to make it a good question worth asking!"*

Comment: If you do not want down votes do not post questions or answers worth of down votes to begin with. A quick browsing of your questions shows a shocking amount of lack of research before asking your question and no attention paid to [How to ask a Good Question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [What not to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 5):

If I were you, I would first ask myself why did I get so much downvotes.

I think we're talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889311/how-do-i-make-an-active-link-affect-the-source-of-an-image-in-html-css-js) in particular.

The downvotes are obviously because your question didn't follow the guidelines from the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

You showed no effort, no research findings, no exact error, not a single line of code (as it seems your question is about coding).

> If I have a set of svg images that I am using as links, as well as a set place for an image in the HTML page, how do I make it so the image that is shown changes depending on which link is active?

You had to give us more information as what have you tried already to achieve this, and how did you actually fail to do so, be precise and clear. Make sure to give the community a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Now to answer your question:

If you really feel that your question is worth keeping, then modify it, fix it, make it an acceptable question. Otherwise, delete it.

If you really feel that your answer to that question is really helpful and will guide future fellow developers, keep it. Otherwise, delete the whole post.

To be honest with you, you better delete it because at the end, it might end up deleted by the community because such an answer:

> If I use jQuery, which is part of CSS, I can solve this problem.

will not help anyone. It is so broad, it doesn't give any details about the way you fixed your problem. It doesn't explain why is it a good approach.

It's not a bad practice to answer your own questions when no one else was able to solve it. A lot of people does that around here when they find out the answer to their question before others had the chance to get it for them.
It's not bad either to delete own posts if you feel that they deserve a delete (which in my opinion, your post deserve that). There's no point of keeping a post that won't help anyone else, and it doesn't really feel like it even helped you at all.

---

### TL;DR

The Stack Overflow community has guidelines for good questions/answers. If the post doesn't follow those guidelines and the post is badly downvoted by the community (Which proves it's not useful) it's always better to delete it. Another option would be to improve it to a point where it becomes a good, solid helpful post, and well appreciated by the community.

Comment: The question that I was talking about was a different one, which got 10 downvotes.

Comment: Well, this one also answers your question here in meta.

Comment: Okay, I'm fairly new here, and at the time of the question I didn't realize that it was not for 'How do I do this?' questions.  I now realize it is for Q&A questions, and extensive research _is_ required.

Comment: That's a great start :)